# Binding 2D Integer array to backing form

Tags: java, arrays, spring, spring-mvc

Need to bind 2D Integer Array to form from jsp.

Eg. `int[][] dimension = { {10,10}, {20,20} };`
Is my array in backing form object say `ScaleImg.java`. Added this class object using addAttribute method in Model.

Now, I want to take input from user for that array 'dimension'(by default values are set while declaring).

I tried this

```
         <form1:input placeholder="Width" path="dimension[0][0]"/> 
         <form1:input placeholder="Width" path="dimension[0][1]"/>

         <form1:input placeholder="Width" path="dimension[1][0]"/> 
         <form1:input placeholder="Width" path="dimension[1][1]"/>
```

but it's not working. Please help.

Comment: Check for `ModelMap` method `addAttribute`.

Comment: I have added this to Model using addAttribute method. Problem is after submitting form it says  'dimension[0][0]' is not a property of ScaleImg.java.